# Trying to understand why a mapping is a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be an abelian group, $G \setminus \{g\}$ be a group $\forall g \in G$.  $$\phi_g : G \rightarrow G \setminus \{g\}, \phi(x) := \begin{cases} e & x = g \\ x & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$\phi$ should be a group homomorphism, according to my notes. But is this really true?

$a \cdot g = c \Rightarrow \phi(ag) = \phi(c) = c, \phi(a) \phi(g) = \phi(a) e = \phi(a) = a \neq c$.

Am I missing something? Does this have anything to do with G being an abelian group?

Comment: are $G_g$ and $G\setminus \{g\}$ groups?

Comment: @JorgeFernández sorry, I added the missing information and fixed the typo of the definition of $\phi$

Comment: What is the operation in $G$ \ {$g$}? It can't be induced from $G$ !!!

Comment: @brick the group G without the element g, which is a group by definition (of this scenario)

Comment: I'm skeptical that this is a homomorphism if $G$ is finite, except in a trivial case. $\phi_{g}$ surjects onto $G-\{g\}$, but if $\phi_{g}$ is a homomorphism then by the first isomorphism theorem $G/\ker(\phi_{g}) \cong G-\{g\}$, which in particular implies $|G-\{g\}| = |G|-1$ divides $|G|$, which is false for all $|G| > 2$. In the case $|G| = 2$, then $\phi_{g}$ is just the trivial homomorphism onto the trivial group...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G\setminus \{g\}$ can only be a group if $G$ is a group with two elements and $g$ is the non-identity element.

To see this suppose $G$ has more than two elements and assume taking away $x$ makes it into a group.

take a non-identity element $y$ different from $x$, then there exists a $b$ so that $yb=x$ since that $b$ is precisely $xb^{-1}$. What is more we can prove $b$ is not $x$ since otherwise $yx=x$ meaning $y=e$.

Then we have $yb=x$ meaning $G\setminus \{x\}$ cannot be a group since it is not closed.